# Calendar Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a Calendar Table with following columns and requirements. I have this calendar table made previously and I am not able to update it to my current requirements.

1. Date
2. Week No
3. Week Name
4. Week Start Date
5. Week End Date
6. Month
7. Month Start Date
8. Month End Date
9. List item
10. Quarter
11. Quarter Start Date
12. Quarter End Date
13. Year

Requirements

- --Week Starts from Sunday and ends at Saturday
- --Week Name should be in format 31Aug--to--06Sep
- --Month should be ending date of Week's Month
- --Calendar should start from 2015-08-31
- --Financial Year should be in format of FY16-17
- --Year should start from 1-Jun Till 31 May
- --Quarter should be of 3 months of above mentioned dates
- --Week No should be incremental number should not get reset after year completion.

The Query

```
DECLARE @StartDate  date = '20150831'
DECLARE @CutoffDate date = '20300101'

;WITH seq(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
  WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)
),
d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate) FROM seq
),
src AS      /*SOURCE TABLE WITH OBJECT DEFINITION*/
(
  SELECT
    TheDate         = CONVERT(date, d),
    TheDay          = DATEPART(DAY,       d),
    TheDayName      = DATENAME(WEEKDAY,   d),
    TheWeek         = DATEPART(WEEK,      d),
    TheDayOfWeek    = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,   d),
    TheMonth        = DATEPART(MONTH,     d),
    TheMonthName    = DATENAME(MONTH,     d),
    TheQuarter      = Concat('Q',DATEPART(Quarter,   d)),
    Financial_Year  = DATEPART(YEAR,      d),
    Financial_Quarter=Datepart(QUARTER,d),
    TheYear         = DATEPART(YEAR,      d),
    TheFirstOfMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), MONTH(d), 1),
    TheFirstOfFYear   = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 4, 1),
    TheFirstOfYear   = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 1, 1),
    TheLastOfYear   = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 12, 31),
    TheDayOfYear    = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, d)
  FROM d
),
Dimension AS
(
  SELECT
    TheDate, 
    TheDay,
    TheDayName,
    TheDayOfWeek,
   -- TheDayOfWeekInMonth = CONVERT(tinyint, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    --                        (PARTITION BY TheFirstOfMonth, TheDayOfWeek ORDER BY TheDate)),
    TheDayOfYear,
    TheWeek,
    TheFirstOfWeek      = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - TheDayOfWeek, TheDate),
    TheLastOfWeek       = DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - TheDayOfWeek, TheDate)),
    
    TheMonth,
    TheMonthName,
    TheFirstOfMonth,
    TheLastOfMonth      = MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheMonth),
    TheFirstOfNextMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, TheFirstOfMonth),
    TheLastOfNextMonth  = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, TheFirstOfMonth)),
    TheQuarter,
    TheFirstOfQuarter   = MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheQuarter),
    TheLastOfQuarter    = MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheQuarter),
    TheYear,
    TheFirstOfYear      = DATEFROMPARTS(TheYear, 1,  1),
    TheFirstOfFYear     = DATEFROMPARTS(TheYear, 4,  1),
    TheLastOfYear,
    MMYYYY              = CONVERT(char(2), CONVERT(char(8), TheDate, 101))
                          + CONVERT(char(4), TheYear),
                            

    Financial_Quarter   = Datepart(Quarter,DATEADD(MONTH, -3, TheFirstOfMonth)), /*Starting Financial Quarter from April*/
    Financial_Year      =CASE
                            WHEN Financial_Quarter = 1 THEN DATEPART(Year,Dateadd(Year,-1,TheFirstofYear)) ELSE THEYEAR END
  FROM src
)
SELECT * FROM Dimension
  ORDER BY TheDate
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

How to convert Months depending on the weeks for example a month starts on Sunday (week also starts from Sunday) date be 01-MM-YYYY and the month should always end on Saturday giving 4 weeks normally in a month. The month cannot start or end with dates of previous week or month it should always have only the whole weeks, starting from Sunday and ending on Saturday.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: How to convert Months depending on the weeks for example a month starts on Sunday (week also starts from Sunday) date be 01-MM-YYYY and the month should always end on Saturday giving 4 weeks normally in a month. The month cannot start or end with dates of previous week or month it should always have only the whole weeks, starting from Sunday and ending on Saturday. Hope you I was able to convey the msg correctly

Comment: Seems like you just need to count the number of sundays in the month; that gives you the "week number". If so, this is just a windowed cumulative `COUNT`.

Comment: Also, this SQL looks very similar to the one in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497418/creating-a-calendar-table-without-recursion/68497481). I suggest you use a set based method to create your table too, if I am honest.

Comment: try to provide minimal viable example and it will be easy to work on. Give a sample input and expected output

Comment: @Larnu yes I am using that query

Comment: @Larnu can you let me know how can I turn off Partition for Week No after year completion. and display the week name in this format 31Aug--to--06Sep

Answer (score 2):

As I mention in the comments, seems you just need a windowed `COUNT`. This is a guess, based on a lack of expected results, but this should get you on the right path. I also use the same set based method I used for your [colleague's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497418/creating-a-calendar-table-without-recursion/68497481):

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate  date = '20150831'
DECLARE @CutoffDate date = '20300101';
/*
; is a terminator, not a "beginingator". It goes at the end of ALL your statements,
not at the start of statements that require the PREVIOUS statement to be properly terminated.
*/
WITH N AS 
    (SELECT N
     FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS
    (SELECT 0 AS I
     UNION ALL
     SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate))
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
     FROM N N1,N N2,N N3, N N4), --Up to 1000 rows. Add more cross joins for more rows
D AS
    (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate) AS d
     FROM Tally T),
Src AS /*SOURCE TABLE WITH OBJECT DEFINITION*/
    (SELECT CONVERT(date, d) AS TheDate,
            DATEPART(DAY, d) AS TheDay,
            DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d) AS TheDayName,
            DATEPART(WEEK, d) AS TheWeek,
            DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d) AS TheDayOfWeek,
            DATEPART(MONTH, d) AS TheMonth,
            DATENAME(MONTH, d) AS TheMonthName,
            CONCAT('Q', DATEPART(QUARTER, d)) AS TheQuarter,
            DATEPART(YEAR, d) AS Financial_Year,
            DATEPART(QUARTER, d) AS Financial_Quarter,
            DATEPART(YEAR, d) AS TheYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), MONTH(d), 1) AS TheFirstOfMonth,
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 4, 1) AS TheFirstOfFYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 1, 1) AS TheFirstOfYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 12, 31) AS TheLastOfYear,
            DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, d) AS TheDayOfYear
     FROM d),
Dimension AS
    (SELECT TheDate,
            TheDay,
            TheDayName,
            TheDayOfWeek,
            CONVERT(tinyint, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TheFirstOfMonth, TheDayOfWeek ORDER BY TheDate)) AS TheDayOfWeekInMonth,
            TheDayOfYear,
            TheWeek,
            DATEADD(DAY, 1 - TheDayOfWeek, TheDate) AS TheFirstOfWeek,
            DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - TheDayOfWeek, TheDate)) AS TheLastOfWeek,
            CONVERT(tinyint, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheMonth ORDER BY TheWeek)) AS TheWeekOfMonth,
            TheMonth,
            TheMonthName,
            TheFirstOfMonth,
            MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheMonth) AS TheLastOfMonth,
            DATEADD(MONTH, 1, TheFirstOfMonth) AS TheFirstOfNextMonth,
            DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, TheFirstOfMonth)) AS TheLastOfNextMonth,
            TheQuarter,
            MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheQuarter) AS TheFirstOfQuarter,
            MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TheYear, TheQuarter) AS TheLastOfQuarter,
            TheYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(TheYear, 1, 1) AS TheFirstOfYear,
            DATEFROMPARTS(TheYear, 4, 1) AS TheFirstOfFYear,
            TheLastOfYear,
            CONVERT(char(2), CONVERT(char(8), TheDate, 101)) + CONVERT(char(4), TheYear) AS MMYYYY,
            DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, TheFirstOfMonth)) AS Financial_Quarter, /*Starting Financial Quarter from April*/
            CASE
                 WHEN Financial_Quarter = 1 THEN DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, TheFirstOfYear))
                 ELSE TheYear
            END AS Financial_Year,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,TheDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(TheDate), MONTH(TheMonth) ORDER BY TheDate) AS TheWeekNo
     FROM src)
SELECT *
FROM Dimension
ORDER BY TheDate;
```

Comment: I desired output is like in this question I found. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43256458/16427257

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single SELECT query that uses the WITH RECURSIVE statement.  It does not require loops procedures etc.

A RECURSIVE SQL common table expression (CTE) is a query that continuously references a previous result until it returns an empty result. It's achieved using a CTE, which in SQL is known as a “WITH” statement.

In the query below, the second date_range with statement has a UNION ALL.  The first query in that statement is the first record of the table, and the subsequent records are all from the UNION ALL second statement where it continuously references itself until it reaches the end_date, as expresses as "WHERE next_date <= end_date"

```
WITH RECURSIVE min_max_dates AS (
  SELECT 
    MIN(start_at) start_date,
    MAX(end_at) end_date 
  FROM table_or_hard_code ay
),
date_range AS (
  select 
    start_date date,
    DATE_TRUNC('month', start_date) month_date,
    MONTH(start_date) as month_num,
    YEAR(start_date) as month_year,
    TO_CHAR((start_date),'MMMM') as month_display,
    MONTHNAME (start_date) as month_short_display,
    CONCAT(TO_CHAR((start_date),'MMMM'), ', ', YEAR(start_date)) as month_year_display,
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, start_date) as next_date,
    start_date,
    end_date
  FROM min_max_dates
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    dr.next_date date,
    DATE_TRUNC('month', dr.next_date) month_date,
    MONTH(dr.next_date) as month_num,
    YEAR(dr.next_date) as month_year,
    TO_CHAR((dr.next_date),'MMMM') as month_display,
    MONTHNAME (dr.next_date) as month_short_display,
    CONCAT(TO_CHAR((dr.next_date),'MMMM'), ', ', YEAR(dr.next_date)) as month_year_display,
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, dr.next_date) as next_date,
    start_date,
    end_date
  FROM date_range dr
  WHERE next_date <= end_date
)
SELECT date, month_date, month_year, month_num, month_display, month_short_display, month_year_display
FROM date_range
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the calendar procedure that we developed, it's too big to post on StackOverflow (~39k characters) or I would post the raw code. You can specify:

- What date range you want to build the table for
- What day you want weeks to start on
- What month you want your fiscal year to start on.

**Link to Procedure and Data Dictionary**

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MGBe0-V24xQuz1CufhnrZo6IYo9_pJss?usp=share_link

This meets all of the requirements except for the specific week label (31Aug--to--06Sep) and a column that gives you a rolling week number that's relative to the table itself and not any calendar date. I'll let you turn to the other posts for those.

**Table screenshots**

Here's a few screenshots of the table the procedure builds so you can decide if it's worth your time:

[image: Table screenshot 1]

[image: Table screenshot 2]

[image: Table screenshot 3]

[image: Table screenshot 4]

[image: Table screenshot 5]

And here's a glance at the simple data dictionary, just for fun:

[image]